# Add Transcript to Audacity Track

Tags: audacity, speech-to-text, transcription

I use Audacity for post-production of a podcast. It would be nice to have a transcription below the audio tracks, so it's easier to navigate.

Is there a way to automatically transcribe a track and add the spoken words as [labels](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/creating_and_selecting_labels.html)?